# Android non-removable notification after application uninstall

Tags: android

I know the question might sound stupid but I will ask it.

Do you guys know if there is a way to display a notification in the notification bar even if the application that started the notification has been uninstalled?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not possible.

Comment: Agreed. If that is possible, it's clearly a bug.